How to compare an integer to an array?
I am doing a Registration code in C, which basically can input multiple accounts.
Now, what I want is to access that specific account through a Log-In function where (Pass == LogIn Pass).
Although my code can already access that specific account (see Inquiry() function), my problem is that when I try to confirm the LogIn_Pass with the password of that specific account, it always returns "Account not Found" even though the user input is correct.
I've already checked that Inquiry() works, and it s based on the inputted Account number in LogIn().
My problem is that the LogIn_Pass does not compare with the password inputted from Registration (accounts[i][4]).
Please see the LogIn Function. The 'welcome' statement never prints. How can I successfully compare them?
Im new in C, and Im stumped. Please help.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char accounts[100][4][100]; 
int num_accounts = 0, confirm_pass, login_pass; 
int acc_num;
int login_pass;

// Function declarations
void Registration();
void Inquiry();
void LogIn();

//Main Function
int main() {
    int n;
    
    
    Registration();
    LogIn();
    
    while (1) {
        printf("\n1. Inquiry\n2. Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        
        switch (n) {
            case 1: 
                Inquiry();
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Exiting...\n");
                return 0;
            default:
                printf("Invalid choice!\n");
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

//Registration Function
void Registration() {
    printf("Enter the number of accounts to register: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_accounts);
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < num_accounts; i++) {
        getchar();
        printf("\nRegistration for Account %d\n", i + 1);
        printf("____________________________\n");
        printf("1. Account name: ");
        fgets(accounts[i][0], sizeof(accounts[i][0]), stdin);
        printf("2. Account number: ");
        fgets(accounts[i][1], sizeof(accounts[i][1]), stdin);
        printf("3. Address: ");
        fgets(accounts[i][2], sizeof(accounts[i][2]), stdin);
        printf("4. Mobile number: ");
        fgets(accounts[i][3], sizeof(accounts[i][3]), stdin);
        
        // Prompt for password creation
        do {
            printf("\n\nCreate Password: ");
            fgets(accounts[i][4], sizeof(accounts[i][4]), stdin);
            printf("Confirm Password: ");
             fgets(accounts[i][5], sizeof(accounts[i][5]), stdin);
            
            if (strcmp(accounts[i][4], accounts[i][5]) == 0) {
                break;
            } else {
                printf("Password does not match!\n");
            }
        } while (1);
    }
}

//LogIn Function
void LogIn() {
    
   
    printf("\nLog In: \n");
    printf("____________________________\n");
    printf("Account number: ");
    scanf("%d", &acc_num);
    printf("Password: ");
    scanf("%d", &login_pass);
    
    // Find the account with the matching account number
    int found = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_accounts; i++) {
         if (acc_num == atoi(accounts[i][1]) && login_pass == atoi(accounts[i][4])) {
            printf("\nWelcome!\n");
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if (!found) {
        printf("\nAccount not found!\n");
    }
}

//Inquiry Function
void Inquiry() {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_accounts; i++) {
        if (acc_num == atoi(accounts[i][1])) {
             printf("Account name: %s", accounts[i][0]);
            printf("Account number: %s", accounts[i][1]);
            printf("Address: %s", accounts[i][2]);
            printf("Mobile number: %s", accounts[i][3]);
            break;
        }
    }
    
}


Are you trying to programme a hash-table?

char accounts[100][4][100]; doesn't work well with fgets(accounts[i][4], sizeof(accounts[i][4]), stdin); (or index 5, either...) You've got to keep track of these things. Use #define values, and not magic numbers that the reader has to check to ensure they are valid...

What is your input? Show what Inquiry() prints before you try to "login". Note fgets() may place newline at the end. However, it shouldn't affect atoi(). Also check return values of scanf() and fgets() for errors. Why getchar()?

I was thinking that the first bracket of char accounts says the limit of accounts that can be inputted.

Yes, I already checked Inquiry() works. The problem is that Inquiry() only runs basing on the account number inputted in the LogIn(). My only problem is that (LogIn_Pass == Pass) does not work

OP: "How can I successfully compare them?"
Answer: by not overwriting them.

char accounts[100][4][100];

shows your intent to record 100 records of 4 fields, each 100 characters long.
Then, when creating accounts:

fgets(accounts[i][4], sizeof(accounts[i][4]), stdin); and...
fgets(accounts[i][5], sizeof(accounts[i][5]), stdin);

are recording information into the imagined rows 5 & 6 (i.e.: beyond the intended 4 rows of data).
When the user enters the first field of record #2, the entry replaces what was the password of record #1. This is unfortunate.

Minimal fix: Instead of "magic numbers", use enum tokens to name the "rows" of each "record"

enum { eName, eAcct, eAddr, eMobl, ePswd, nFlds };

NB: Position this definition of these compiler tokens at the top of the source code (after the #include lines).

Then, something like:
        printf("1. Account name: ");
        fgets(accounts[i][ eName ], sizeof(accounts[i][ eName ]), stdin);
        printf("2. Account number: ");
        fgets(accounts[i][ eAcct ], sizeof(accounts[i][ eAcct ]), stdin);
        printf("3. Address: ");
        fgets(accounts[i][ eAddr ], sizeof(accounts[i][ eAddr ]), stdin);
        printf("4. Mobile number: ");
        fgets(accounts[i][ eMobl ], sizeof(accounts[i][ eMobl ]), stdin);
        
        // Prompt for password creation
        do {
            printf("\n\nCreate Password: ");
            fgets(accounts[i][ ePswd ], sizeof(accounts[i][ ePswd ]), stdin);

            printf("Confirm Password: ");
            char tmp[ sizeof accounts[i][ ePswd ] ]; // 2nd entry into temp buffer

            fgets( tmp, sizeof tmp, stdin);
            
            if (strcmp( accounts[i][ ePswd ], tmp ) == 0)
                break;

            printf("Password does not match!\n");
        } while (1);

Then fix up the allocation line:

char accounts[100][ nFlds ][100];


Then, go through entire code, replacing ALL the magic numbers with tokens assigned a definite value in only one location.

Too much "newbie optimism" without careful attention to every important detail.
Code shown here has not been compiled or tested. For instructional purposes only.

What happens when an enthusiastic user tries to create 162 accounts?
Does your program handle that gracefully?
Learning is tough. Keep at it...

OMG! You're right!  The problem all along is the declared [4] fields. Also, thank you for your insight, I do see that enum is more convenient to use. Thank you so much!

@Jade You're welcome. Hope this helps you move forward. Recommendation: You've got comments in code that simply state "what" the program is doing. Better to assume the reader understands and can read C code easily. Better to add only a few comments only to explain why author made decision to code algorithm "this way." (dis/advantages of this way, maybe vs. alternatives.) Keep at it... Enjoy the struggle...
